# couldn't execute "python": no such file or directory

Tags: python, tcl

I am trying to execute python from tcl script but i have the message error "couldn't execute "python": no such file or directory"

This is my code:
test.py

```
print('hello')
```

exec.tcl

```
set out [exec python test.py]
puts $out
```

and in Windows PowerShell i use this command:

```
tclsh exec.tcl
```

Could you please help me fix this error?

Comment: Provide the full path to the python exe instead of relying on PATH.

Comment: Looks like the Python executable isn't in a directory that is on your `PATH` environment variable. Or maybe you've not installed it at all; the result would look the same at this point.

Comment: @Paxz or just add Python executable to `PATH` if it was supposed to be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your Python's version, it may use py as command. You should try using 'py' instead of 'python'.

More info:
[Python Launcher for Windows (Python Docs)](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher)